# How to configure Karma to provide a singleton global service?

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, angular-services, angular-test

I am writing some Angular unit tests that the majority all require the same mocked service.  Instead of having to configure the TestBed in every single spec file, is there a way to set up Karma where this service is available globally for all tests everywhere?  Additionally, this service needs to be a singleton and NOT have a new instance created every time it's injected.  If so, where is this configured (I cannot determine this from reading the documentation)?

Comment: This is not the intent of karma, I don't think it is possible.

Comment: Sharing the state between unit tests should almost always be avoided. Can you explain your case? What is this service and why you can't just use global variable if you need global state? As it was stated, this isn't Karma's responsibility, it's just test runner.

Comment: I am using Karma + Jasmine for an integration type of test.  I am making an actual HTTP call to an API endpoint to acquire a server configuration then executing tests to confirm that client-side contracts adhere to it.  This works, but am I trying to avoid repeated calls to the API server since the configuration will always be the same. Yeah, I know, I'm not using Karma as intended but I have not found an alternative approach to what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Wrap common functionality with NgModule and import the module in all specs. That's a declarative way to do that. Angular doesn't provide a way to add providers globally to test bed.